# How to register a service using Spring Cloud Consul

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, consul

I have registered a service using **Spring Cloud Consul**, but for this I had to run a **Consul local agent** which establishes a channel communication to **Consul server node** (running as bootstrap).

*For example:*

```
#Server
consul agent -server -bootstrap -bind -data-dir data -ui-dir web_ui

#Desktop
consul agent -data-dir consul -ui-dir consul/dist -join server_ip_address
```

Is there any way to avoid of having this local agent in my desktop, I mean from my desktop **Spring Cloud Consul** would register the service to server node?

An example of this is what Netflix Eureka client does with Netflix Eureka server, no external agents running in machines to bind services names.

Comment: That's the recommend way to run consul

Comment: Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: Not that I know of. You'd need to talk to someone that works on consul for hashicorp.

Comment: I have tested to set up the properties spring.cloud.consul.host and spring.cloud.consul.port with server node address, but it did not work.

Comment: @ElLordCode Consul is agent based.  There is no real way around using an agent.  That is part of the reason Consul works with any service on a host.

Comment: This is a great question. What about when that service is not running on a server? For example its running in a spring boot app running on kubernetes or cloud Foundry. There is no agent. How do you register those services?

Comment: I have opened an issue to consul github asking about it, and the answer I got was that the default behavior expected. So Consul was developed to use a local agent where needs to run,  and there's no other way to  run without it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use property file or yaml file i just give sample yaml file

**application.yml**

```
# Configure this Discovery Server
spring:
  cloud:
    consul:
      host: localhost
      port: 8500
```

**bootstrap.yml**

```
spring:
  application:
          name: service-name
```

Comment: It is recommended that both of them go into bootstrap.yml